# Preventing a class to be instanstiated

Tags: c++, abstract

Recently I've been asked the following question:

You're writing a base class, which you want other people to be able to derive from for their personal use. You would like that no one will be able to instanstiate the Base class you're writing (only objects of derived classes).
How would you implement the class?

I have thought of two solutions:

One, is making the base class abstract (by adding a pure virtual function).

Second, put the constructor under the protected section, so no one from the outside will be able to create an instance of it, only the derived classes.

My question is, what's the difference between my solutions (in all aspect you can think of)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A protected constructor is sensible, but doesn't prevent the class from being instantiated:

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    Foo() = default;
public:
    static Foo make() { return Foo(); }
};

int main()
{
    auto f = Foo::make(); 
}
```

On the other hand, an abstract class can never be instantiated, which is what you may want here.

The important question, however, is whether you actually need a *polymorphic* hierarchy in which you need to decide types at runtime and handle a heterogeneous collection of objects via base pointers. If so, then an abstract base it the way to go. If not, you cannot have an abstract class without virtual functions, and a protected constructor (and destructor) is the only way to signal that you want an uninstantiable base.

Comment: I'd argue that a `protected` constructor is enough to prevent this class from being instantiated. You're "cheating" slightly by adding a static member function to return an instance. Even with the cheat, a `protected` or `private` copy constructor would stop you.

Comment: @NikBougalis: I could also have a static function returning a `new Foo` -- no copying needed :-S

Comment: right - but the point is that if you're going to cheat then the game is over. But you did highlight how a private constructor isn't enough, and how it differs from having a pure virtual function in the base class to prevent instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

A pure virtual function adds the overhead of a virtual function table to your base class, which can be a problem if you need to keep the objects really small. This overhead can be avoided by using protected constructors and/or a protected destructor. The protected destructor is helpful to prevent accidential deletion through a base-class pointer which, in the absence of a *virtual* destructor, would lead to undefined behaviour.